# What's the use of expression.init() in Swift

Tags: initialization, swift

The Swift Programming Language guide, page Language Reference -> [Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-XID_655), section Postfix Expressions -> Initializer Expression talks about the syntax

```
<expression>.init(<initializer arguments>)
```

When would you use this (apart from `self.init()` and `super.init()` which are already covered in other parts of the grammar)? It seems to me that in any case where the above expression is valid (and the expression is not `self` or `super`), you can also do:

```
<expression>(<initializer arguments>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the syntax template looks like this:

```
<expression>.init(<initializer arguments>)
```

the grammar just defines an [initializer-expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/initializer-expression) as:

```
initializer-expression → postfix-expression . init­
```

Note that the invocation arguments are not included. This matches constructs like `A.init`, and is necessary because `init` is a keyword, so `A.init` will not match [explicit-member-expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/explicit-member-expression) (which requires an identifier rather than a keyword as the member name).

Initializer expressions are a part of the grammar because you can invoke an initializer that belongs to class that is not the direct superclass of the class you are writing (`C` invokes `A.init` in this example):

```
class A {
    var property: String
    init() {
        property = "hello"
    }
}

class B: A {
    init() {
        super.init()
        property = "goodbye"
    }
}

class C: B {
    init() {
        super.init()
        A.init()
    }
}

C().property // "hello"
```

I don't think there are many use cases for this, but both the grammar and the compiler allow it and this example compiles and runs correctly.

You can also use an initializer expression in the global scope like you would a normal initializer. The following two lines are equivalent:

```
String(10)
String.init(10)
```

Comment: But the `super.init()` (B's init) already calls `super.init()` (A's init). So why would you call A's init again?

Comment: Again, there aren't many use cases, but you could, e.g., invoke a different initializer of A from the one B invokes.

Comment: This is very interesting. So it is meant to be used in an initializer. What confused me is that the compiler let me use `A.init()` at the global level too, and there it returns a new instance (might be a compiler bug); whereas inside an initializer it doesn't return. Also, if I put `A.init()` in a method, it crashes ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure why they added this to the language at all. File a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/), perhaps?